# Issue delegate Protocol not working properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, alamofire, protocols

Implemented protocol to observe web services download file progress but I am not getting any error but function is not invoking. Even I have set the breakpoint. What am I doing in code please anyone can guide.

- One pure swift class which is DataProvider contains download
- Function.  Calling in ViewController to observe progress.

DataProvider Swift Class:

```
protocol MyWebServiceProtocol: class {
   func progress(_ fractionCompleted: Double)
   func downloadDidSucceed()
   func downloadDidFail(error: Error)
}

// in class
weak var delegate: MyWebServiceProtocol?

//Alamofire

Alamofire.download(
            url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: nil,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: nil,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //progress closure
                self.delegate?.progress(progress.fractionCompleted)

                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                //result closure
                callback(DefaultDownloadResponse.response?.statusCode == 200, DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL?.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: ""))
                print(DefaultDownloadResponse)
                self.delegate?.downloadDidSucceed()
            })
```

ViewController:

```
 var webService: DataProvider?

    convenience init(webService: DataProvider = DataProvider()) {
        self.init()
        self.webService = webService
        self.webService?.delegate = self

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }


extension DownloadViewController: MyWebServiceProtocol {
    func progress(_ fractionCompleted: Double) {
        print(fractionCompleted)
    }

    func downloadDidSucceed() {
        print("download")
    }


    func downloadDidFail(error: Error) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the `print()` lines in your `.download` closure ***are*** showing in debug console, but the ones in your extension are ***not***? Put this line `print(self.delegate)` before calling the delegate func(s) and see if it has been initialized properly.

Comment: @DonMag where I place this `print(self.delegate)` line? in ViewController

Comment: In your download closure... so, immediately before `self.delegate?.progress(progress.fractionCompleted)` and immediately before `self.delegate?.downloadDidSucceed()`

Comment: giving `nil` on both states. Tested many times give `nil`

Comment: OK - then you need to post a bit more code. Where is `convenience init(webService...`? How are you calling that?

Comment: `convenience init(webService...` is in `ViewController` and I have common class which is DataProvider pure swift class.  I also mentioned in code.  Actually I have to observe progress in `ViewController` for web services and download files.  The main purpose for creating `protocols`

Comment: Without showing more code, can't help you. Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: DataProvider file code is too lengthy. Can you tell me which code I will share with you for better understanding?
Once more thing comes in my mind Is it possible to observe progress data in a ViewController because I am using callback functions in ViewController then it hits to `DataProvider. Alamofire function `

Comment: Because you're getting `nil` from `print(self.delegate)`, it is clear that the delegate is ***not*** being set. Without seeing how you are instantiating and using `DataProvider` class, there is no way of helping you. I'd suggest either posting your code on a paste site (such as pastebin.com) or creating a GitHub repo of your project.

Comment: Ok I will create a sample one and push to GitHub and let you know.

Comment: Don't set the delegate inside init to the class (self), it should be too early. Maybe inside viewDidLoad and make sure your call back in Alamofire is calling.